# Need to increase the year in the date I am getting from jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am getting `mm/dd/yy` format from a datepicker and now I need to show the date in a `div` but after increase the year by 1 . For e.g. `04/12/2012` This is what i have selected from datepicker now I need to increase the year part i.e 2012 to 2013 and show it to another div using javascript.

Need help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var d = new Date(*dateString*);
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 365);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var d = new Date(my_date);
    var next_year = d.getFullYear()+1;
    d.setFullYear(next_year);
```

Will get you date with next year